# Verbs for trash in a littering

Tags: word-request, verbs

What are the verbs for trash in a littering? Throwing away or dumping a trash? Thank you! I have looked it up in Merrian-Webster dictionary but find nothing.

Comment: Can you give an example? I think I know what you want, but I want to make sure.

Comment: What do you understand "littering" to mean? An example of a sentence with a blank where you would like to use the verb would help us understand your question better.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of verbs used for garbage / trash:

> [*To throw away*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/throw)
>
> [*To discard*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/discard)
>
> [*To dump*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/dump)
>
> [*To dispose of*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/dispose%20of)

"Throw away" is the one most commonly applied to garbage:

> The US **throws away** almost half of the food we produce.

You can also use "throw out""

> I don't want this anymore, could you please **throw it out** for me?

In addition, in AmE, we use "take out the trash/garbage" to describe the act of throwing something away, most often to mean when you take a household trash bag to an outside garbage can:

> As one of his chores, my son is supposed to **take out the trash** every day, but he usually forgets.

**Litter** is a specific kind of trash, usually to mean the stuff you see randomly discarded in public places and not properly placed in a trash can.  **Littering** is the act of creating *litter*, to throw something out on the ground or anywhere other than a proper trash can.

Some other notes.  In AmE it's "garbage" or "trash" while in BrE it's "rubbish".  The large receptacle to hold trash in AmE is a "trash can" or "garbage can" (although "bin" is becoming more common instead of "can") while in BrE it's "dustbin" or "rubbish bin".